# Python lambda: TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I was trying to extract information from `df['matrix']` into four new columns. The `df['matrix']` look like this:

```
  id       matrix
   0  {'status': 'ZERO_RESULTS'}
   1  {'distance': {'text': '3,899 km', 'value': 3898595}, 'duration': {'text': '1 day 13 hours', 'value': 133445}, 'status': 'OK'}
   2  {'distance': {'text': '2,065 km', 'value': 2065157}, 'duration': {'text': '20 hours 7 mins', 'value': 72393}, 'status': 'OK'}
```

my code:

```
df['dist_value'] = df['matrix'].apply(lambda x: round((x['distance']['value']) / 1000) if "status" not in x else None)
df['dist_text'] = df['matrix'].apply(lambda x: x['distance']['text'] if "status" not in x else None)

df['duration_value'] = df['matrix'].apply(lambda x: float("%.2f" %((x['duration']['value'])/60/60)) if "status" not in x else None)
df['duration_text'] = df['matrix'].apply(lambda x: x['duration']['text'] if "status" not in x else None)
```

I get the following error:

```
df['dist_value'] = df['matrix'].apply(lambda x: round((x['distance']['value']) / 1000) if "status" not in x else None)
TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable
```

Comment: Seems like `x` is a float, not an iterable (and so `in x`) fails. `x` is an element of `df['matrix']` so guessing one is of a different type.

Comment: Are you sure your elements inside the `'matrix'` columns are dictionaries any more?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem with the data given as above. With the previous comment in mind, you have probably altered the data in between, causing it not to be a dict anymore. Try and see if e.g. `df['matrix'].apply(lambda x: x.keys())` works.

Comment: I only have two scenarios in my matrix column (either 'status': 'ZERO_RESULTS' or reported results in a standard format). what I want is to skip the operation to rows contains  'status': 'ZERO_RESULTS'. Even I narrow down to 1st row it will report error so I guess this is something to do with "if "status" not in x "

Comment: does `"status" not in x.keys()` resolve the error?

Comment: no, still the same issue reported

Comment: In your data, you have `'status'` in all the rows. So just checking status in keys is not going to work

Answer (score 3):

Since you are checking if "status" is in x and it looks like sometimes x is not a string. You can cast your x to string with str(x).

Hope it will solve your problem.