# How do I set this dataframe column up so I can iterate over it?

Tags: python, pandas, instagram

I have a list of instagram posts, and I am trying to pull all the words that start with @ out of the description (the comment of the post) so I can put together a network graph of everyone that is talking about that hashtag.

The dataframe is ultimately pretty simple. I have a picture of df2 (just the columns I am using).

I can't post the image yet because I don't have a 10 rep, but here is the link - https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGRs0.png

I was successful in doing this yesterday by creating a new column using str.split() to break the description into a list of each word, then used a lambda to iterate through that column and remove each word from each list that didn't start with @.  Worked great.

Then today I went to do it again with a new csv that I got from the same source, but I got an error - "TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable"

```
df = pd.read_csv("import instagram hashtag.csv")
df.drop_duplicates(subset='id', keep='first', inplace=False)
df['username'] = ('@' + df['username'])

df2 = df[['username', 'pubDate', 'id', 'description']]
#creating a column 'listsplit' that has lists of just the @ people from 'Text'
df2['listsplit'] = df2['description'].str.split().apply(lambda x: [i for i 
in x if i.startswith('@')])

# creating new columns that just have one @ per column
df2 = pd.concat([df2,df2['listsplit'].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)

#creating the csv
df2.to_csv('@ list from instagram.csv')
```

The error was for the line with the lambda.

Again, yesterday it worked, and today it doesn't.  I guess I need to do a step before I do the str.split() to normalize the data and make it so it doesn't create a float, but I am really new to this and have no idea.

Is there something I can put in before I run that line that will make sure i don't get something that will turn a list into a float object?  Or is there a simpler way to do this?

Thanks, and sorry if this is an easy question.  I really tried searching everywhere and am just lost.

Comment: look at your error :) print `df.dtypes`. You'll see that one of your values is a float (meaning numbers). you can't perform your operations like on a number. search how to convert that column to a string type

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python lambda: TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51989301/python-lambda-typeerror-argument-of-type-float-is-not-iterable)

Comment: OMG i'm an idiot!  THANK YOU!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Just needed to convert 'description' column to a string type before I split it.

```
df2['description'] = df2['description'].astype(str)
```